# Something with javascript possibly connected with locale

Tags: javascript, forms, jstl

I made confirmation window showing by clicking a button on my page. For Russian locale it works perfect, but when I switch it to English, it shows nothing. Here is the code of button:

```
<form method="POST" 
action="Link.do?method=newsList"
onsubmit="return confirm('<fmt:message key="body.onsubmit.cancel" />')">
<input type="submit" 
    value="CANCEL">
</form>
```

Also want to say that `body.onsubmit.cancel` property exists in all property files and I can connect to it successfull. Don't really know what's wrong. Will be gratefull for your help.

Comment: it shows confirmation window http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php

Comment: the code that you posted is not what the client sees, right? the part in the single quotes (<fmt:message .../>) is something that is processed on the server before it sends the markup to the client, right?

Comment: so it seems that the problem with the locale is on the server side. when you switch to english, what is the markup that the client sees?

Comment: when I switch to english everything works perfect,including this tag. I wrote it separately from js and it gave me message as supposed. And I have other scrips which include tags like this one and works great.

Comment: in your original post you said it works for Russian but for English it shows nothing. I am confused.

Comment: but in this js it shows nothing,just redirects me to page. When in russian locale it shows confirmation window with message as I wanted

Comment: the way to debug this is to see the source of the page that was sent to the client when you switch to the locale that does not work and see if the code is correct. for example if your message contains quotes then the syntax will be invalid in the resulting script if the quotes are not escaped.

Comment: thank you! you were right about wrong syntax in message. feel myself stupid now

Comment: I have moved it to an answer. please do not feel stupid. this issue does not indicate the level of one's cleverness.

Comment: просто глаз "замылился" и все :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way to debug this is to see the source of the page that was sent to the client when you switch to the locale that does not work and see if the code is correct. for example if your message contains quotes then the syntax will be invalid in the resulting script if the quotes are not escaped.